# In pandas, how to find the row/index where the cumulative sum is greater than a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like find the row (index) where the cumulative sum of the values in some column exceeds a threshold.

I can, and do, find this location using a simple loop, like below:

```
def sum_to(df, col, threshold):
    s = 0
    for r in df.iterrows():
        if s + r[1][col] > threshold:
            return r[0]
        else:
            s += r[1][col]

    return len(df)
```

However, I would like to know if there is a better/nicer way to achieve this in Pandas.

Comment: Yes. There is a better way. Can we see your data in text form edited into your question? Hoping that isn't too much to ask, it really makes life easy when answering questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is probably

```
df[col].cumsum().searchsorted(threshold)
```

but this assumes that you have no negative numbers in your column.

Comment: No, I don't have negative values. This will work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df[df['A'].cumsum() > 5]
#  A
#2 3
#3 4
#4 5
```