# How to find the row index of Pandas dataframe at which a column CumSum equals X?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

Consider the following DataFrame `df`:

```
index    A
    0   -1
    1    0
    2    1
    3   -1  # <==== here, df['A'].cumsum() == 0, starting from last row 
    4   -1
    5   -1
    6    1
    7   -1
    8    1
    9    1
    10   1
```

I am trying to determine at which row the cumulative sum of `A` — **counted from the last row** —   equals zero.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797596/in-pandas-how-to-find-the-row-index-where-the-cumulative-sum-is-greater-than-a), the solution will not work if a column contains negative values, which is my case.

Moving from top to bottom I presume

```
df[df['A'].cumsum() == 0]
```

would work but this procedure would need to be reversed.

Do you have any pointers in how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[::-1]` can reverse any series or list:

```
df[df['A'][::-1].cumsum()==0]
```

Comment: Even though same answer , but the answer itself is correct . To the downvoter :  if you downvote please left a reason , thank you ~

Comment: Upvote for correct result ~

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[::-1]` to get the reveresed `cumsum`. This will return all results where the `cumsum` = 0:

```
df[df['A'][::-1].cumsum() == 0]

   index    A
0   0      -1
3   3      -1
```

If you just want the last then do:

```
df[df['A'][::-1].cumsum() == 0].iloc[-1]

index    3
A       -1
```